# Issue with Unix time converting to date

Tags: javascript, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have the following code in Javascript:

```
//obj.uploadDate = 1466679630387
temp = new Date(obj.uploadDate);
uploadDate =  temp.toString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

For some reason, the value of `uploadDate` is `NaN-NaN-NaN NaN:NaN:NaN`, instead of a formatted date.

What could be the issue?

Comment: there could b n-number of issue

Comment: What is this? Can you explain?

Comment: `obj.uploadDate`  is not supported date format. What is the value of `obj.uploadDate` you have passing

Comment: Why? I've managed to convert it via http://www.epochconverter.com/.

Comment: I don't get the same issue you get but I also don't think you can format a JavaScript date that way.  Here's another answer about formatting JavaScript dates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: Are you using any kind of library? Which JS engine?

Comment: I'm using `date.js`. As for the engine, i don't use any as far as i know.

Comment: Anyone? How can this issue can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i had to convert to number, and now it's works great.

```
temp = new Date(Number(obj.uploadDate));
uploadDate =  temp.toString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```